# How to limit entity number using entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

With the Persistence provider Hibernate, how to limit entity number using entity
Assume we have an `Address` entity, how to limit we can only have 10 addresses for a user?

I want to restrict this on entity level.

Answer (score 2):

annotate the maximum number of children objects allowed using `@Size` annotation

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Size(max = 2)
private List<Child> children;
```

If the children exceeded the limit, it will throw below `Exception` during persist time

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [org.myapp.Parent] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 0 and 2', propertyPath=childs, rootBeanClass=class org.myapp.Parent, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
]
```

also you can specify the `min` number of objects.

need to include below dependency in pom if hibernate is used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>{hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! But where is the @Size annotation from?

Comment: Actually, what i want is that we can only insert 10 Address records. Is that possible using @Size?

Comment: @ZhijieLiu `min=10, max=10` to persist only records having 10 addresses, `min=0, max=10` to persist records having addresses between 0-10

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mysql this might help you for backend(database).

```
 ALTER TABLE tbl_name MAX_ROWS=1000000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=nnn;
```

for front end

```
List<entity> list=new ArrayList<entity>();
if(list.size()>10){
      //some condtions
     }
```

this way you can set the limit table rows